# Nginx cache mkdir failed (2: No such file or directory) while reading upstream

Tags: nginx, selinux

Edit for **answer**:

It's the selinux causes this problem, the temporary solution is to run this command: sudo semanage permissive -a httpd_t

But you shouldn't do that, because of security reasons. I found an article wrote by Danila Vershinin on nginx selinux configuration, if you have the same problem like me, you should read it.

Original question:

I have a wordpress + woocommerce website on a nginx server (centos 7), I want to make nginx fastcgi cache work, but it always get miss or passby, never hit.

Here is the errer log:

```
2018/11/11 00:00:00 [crit] 1900#0: *1 mkdir() "/etc/nginx/cache/0/53" failed (2: No such file or directory) while reading upstream, client: 111.111.111.111, server: www.example.com, request: "GET /page2/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock:", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/page1/"
```

So how do I solve this problem to make cache work? Thanks!

PS:

Cache will be stored in /etc/nginx/cache, its permission is 700(drwx------), user and group is nginx:root

Here is the related nginx conf:

```
fastcgi_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=WORDPRESS:500m inactive=240m;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
```

Here is the upstream conf:

```
upstream php-fpm {
    server unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
}
```

Here are some lines from the /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf:

```
user = nginx
group = nginx
listen = /run/php-fpm/www.sock
listen.owner = nobody
listen.group = nobody
listen.mode = 0660
listen.acl_users = nginx
```

Comment: Can you please edit your post to show "top", so we can confirm the user the nginx master / child processes are running as? Also an "ls -l" showing the folder permissions of the /etc/nginx/cache folder. This really looks like a permissions issue.

Comment: Hi @Tim, I finally found out what cause the problem, it's selinux. So after I run this command: sudo semanage permissive -a httpd_t, the fastcgi cache works.

Comment: Please write a full answer to your own question, and in 24 hours mark it as accepted, to help others who have this problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question here.

The culprit is selinux.

Basically you need to make nginx comply with selinux's policy to nginx, which is defined as httpd_t. Run the below commands.

- sudo semanage permissive -a httpd_t
- sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/nginx/cache
- sudo chown -R nginx /var/lib/nginx
- sudo restorecon -Rv /var/lib/nginx
- Go to your nginx conf, change your cache location to /var/lib/nginx/cache
- sudo matchpathcon -V /var/lib/nginx/microcache
- sudo semanage permissive -d httpd_t

Simple explanation:

- First command is enough to make cache work, but it's not safe, because it allows nginx to get around selinux.
- Why /var/lib/nginx? This directory is already allowed by selinux.